# Is it possible to do a "re-cache" through htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, jpeg

I have a static website with about 520 HTML pages or so. As I don't need to modify the content frequently, I chose to make it static (HTML + CSS + JS) years ago. However, in addition to some things to optimize, I added the mod_expire in htaccess file.

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
```

Now I need to change the images (only jpg) of the 520 pages, but with these lines above I know that the user will have to clear the browser's cache to view the new images.

My question is is there any method that does a "re-cache" through htaccess so the new images are seen without users having to clear? Or is it only possible through the traditional method by adding "v=2", for example, after the extension in the file name in the link?

I really don't want to have to do this in 520 pages, each containing 10+ photos per page.

I tried removing the mod_expire line from htaccess, but I'm still seeing the old image!

Comment: _"I tried removing the mod_expire line from htaccess, but I'm still seeing the old image!"_ - if a client already has the image cached, and is still within the given expiry time - then it has no reason to make a new request to the server, and therefor it won't notice your change either.

Comment: See my answer here Matheo and see if this helps your situation at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526917/how-to-purge-apache-to-force-browser-to-clear-cache-and-load-files/51533581#51533581 - I've used this to force cache revalidation in the past.

Comment: Thank you, Joe! I had already seen your answer to that post when I was searching, but I just had a few questions. If you can enlighten me, I would be very grateful! I would replace the lines I mentioned in my post with yours, correct? If yes, would I keep the lines you suggested in the other thread forever? And if so, wouldn't it mean that the client side has to download the image with each visit, or does the code you suggested keep optimizing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ExpiresDefault "access minus 1 seconds"
```

Comment: Thanks, flypig! But this modification would make the client's browser have to download the image every time it visited the page, wouldn't it? In this case, I would modify the images and not touch them for a long time.

Comment: `minus` is not a valid keyword so this would likely result in a 500 error. But the use of `ExpiresDefault` assumes the OP has removed the `ExpiresByType` directive. BUT, if the resource is already cached then what's the point of this?!